# Spring boot REST call returns 404 on a Controller from an external JAR

Tags: java, spring, rest, jar, spring-boot

I've created an external JAR which contains a simple Spring REST controller, which contains the following piece of code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/world")
  public Hello hello() {
    System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    return new Hello(1L, "Hello World");
  }

}
```

I then compile this small project into a jar called ***hello.jar*** which i then add to the class path of my Spring Boot application and start the application.

I've also added the package to ComponentScan like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
// @Controller
// @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"main.java.foo.hello" })
@EnableEntityLinks
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)classLoader).getURLs();
    for (URL url : urls) {
      if (url.getPath().contains("hello")) {
        System.out.println(url.getPath());
      }
    }

    SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
  }
}
```

Because of the print out I can see that the jar is loaded into the application and by adding logging to the Spring Boot Application I can see that the Controller is scanned and is picked up (or at least it seems to be).

However went I browse (via chrome) or make a REST call (via Advance REST client) to "***localhost:8765/hello/world***" (I start my server on port 8765), I get 404 error.

Other Rest Controllers (from within the application, not the external JAR) seem to be working fine as all REST calls return the appropriate results.

Does anyone think they know why 404 is returned?

Comment: ´@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"main.java.foo.hello" })` This looks really strange. Are you really sure, that your package is called `main.java.foo.hello`? Usually `main/java` is part of the Maven folder structure and only `foo.hello` would be the package name.

Comment: That code is so weird. `@SpringBootApplication` is meta-annotated with `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so you can remove these. Is your controller in the `main.java.foo.hello` package? (That's also weird!). You can add the actuator and see if it shows up as a bean on `/beans`

Comment: Yes the controller is in that package (yes i know it's weird but its POC not production code). What's an actuator (sorry I am a bit new to this)?

Comment: how did you solve this issue? I am also having the same problem

Comment: Hi, wish I remembered how I fixed it. Both I would guess that the controller wasn't being picked up by the component scan

Comment: Hi there again. I've solved this problem. I added ${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/Catalina/localhost/${APP_NAME}.xml and in this file added application classloader. In tomcat 8+ this is JarResources property, in tomcat less than 8 version it is Loader property. Here my gist with additional explanation https://gist.github.com/durdyev/542dffb60beb30f5c6ce293418555ef7